# iterate map with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

will i'm using spring mvc with ajax for my application , my issue is that i don't know how i can iterate a map that i sent from spring controller.

Controller code

```
                    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    String json = "";
                    try {

                        json = mapper.writeValueAsString(ser.StatistiquesCompte());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("erreur ici");
                    }

                     return json;
```

and my ajax code look like that :

```
            $.ajax({
                url : 'Stats',
                success : function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
```

my result is like that :  {"Key":10,"Key1",30} how i am supposed to iterate this map.

Comment: means `data` holds this value `{"Key":10,"Key1",30}`. right?

Comment: yeah correct @Ranjith

Answer (score 1):

using a for loop

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Stats',
    success: function (data) {
        for (var item in data) {
            // log key , value
            console.log(item, data[item]);
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: not good , this loop is displaying char by char , what i need is something like  a map  key and his value in the same iteration.

Comment: @nedaljedidi You still have it, item is the key and data[item] is value, this is faster than $.each

Comment: @Ranjith The link you sent has this ""for() loop is over 8x faster", that's a good enough reason, and this is a simple iteration anyway, No need for chaining and other advantages of $.each

Comment: still not working good , its not giving me what i want , it displays index from 0 to 10 or some letters.

Answer (score 0):

Itreate your response `data` like this

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'Stats',
    success : function(data) {
         $.each(data , function( key, value ) {
             console.log( key + ": " + value ); // Key : 10
         });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already know what keys are in your response JSON (which holds good for any design that returns JSON responses), the best thing to do is use `JSON.parse`:

```
      $.ajax({
            url : 'Stats',
            success : function(data) {
                var json = JSON.parse(data);
                alert(json.Key1);
                alert(json.Key);
            }
        });
```